# What is the meaning of the notation $S(V)/(V_1)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space and $S(V)$ the symmetric algebra of $V$. Let $V_1$ be a subspace of $V$. In a lecture, I encounter the notation $S(V)/(V_1)$. Does $S(V)/(V_1)$ mean the quotient of $S(V)$ by the ideal generate by $V_1$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Though this is not my field, I can still say "yes" with some certainty. Those are the standard notations for ideals and quotient spaces. If it means something else, then someone is stepping on widespread conventions.

Comment: That would also be my guess.